# Does HTML Compression make a difference in performance?

Tags: python, html, web, jinja2

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2-htmlcompress

-- jinja2-htmlcompress

```
a Jinja2 extension that removes whitespace between HTML tags.
```

Is html compression really worth it? It makes the source look ugly. Does it help with performance though, if so, by how much, and is it noticeable by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt the amount of redundant white space is really going to be worth it for most HTML. If I were that worried, I'd just make sure to set my front-end webserver to gzip the page if possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are other reasons for minifying html. For example, I have to do that cause I'm sending an html email and some clients (like gmail) just cut off the message after some point.

So, in this case, decreasing the size of the generated html increases the amount of information that the user will actually see in the email client. And I don't think they support gzipping the content.

I'm using the htmlmin library: https://github.com/mankyd/htmlmin

There's also a front-end for Django: https://github.com/cobrateam/django-htmlmin

Answer (score 0):

> It makes the source look ugly

This doesn't matter at all. You wouldn't run the compressor during development. You would develop on uncompressed files and run the compressor as part of your build process (just as you would do with JavaScript minification for example).

> Does it help with performance though, if so, by how much, and is it noticeable by the user?

Yes, it helps with performance because it reduces the size of the file that has to be downloaded by the browser. The actual saving obviously depends on the original size of the file, but on modern connections the difference is unlikely to be noticeable. It could definitely still be beneficial though, especially for pages optimised for mobile.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate: Wouldn't gzip compression also reduce the size, by an even larger margin?

Comment: The two aren't _necessarily_ mutually exclusive -- the fact that the whitespace isn't semantic is information unknown to gzip.

Comment: @delnan - Yes, it would. You can still do both, but you'd ideally want to run some comparisons between gzipped and compressed, and gzipped and uncompressed.

Comment: I think the performance reason is not about being faster for the individual browser, but rather less overall bandwidth load on the server. Its not a big deal for a client to download 80k vs 10k but that is an 8x savings to the server when it is serving oodles of clients.

Comment: @jdi an 8x savings _definitely_ matters if you're on a slow connection, like a smartphone.

Comment: Or that :) i guess it depends on the savings. But the factor usually impacts the server more than the client as it compounds.

Answer (score 0):

Savings from whitespace are marginal, at least if you **use gzip compression**.

In some situations, it may make the parsing and DOM faster: you not only save the bytes for the whitespace, but these may show up as additional "text" nodes in parsing.

However, I'm quite convinced that **to many users, the main use of this is to somewhat obfuscate your source code**. Which doesn't make too much sense, as everybody should know his tools on how to reformat HTML to make it readable again.